# Can I use store-bought orange juice instead of fresh squeezed

Tags: substitutions

**Can I use store-bought orange juice instead of fresh squeezed?**

I don't have a juicer and the recipe assumes fresh squeezed juices...
Is there a big enough reason to go through the hassle for a weeknight dinner?

Comment: What are you making?

Comment: Braised pork shoulder... Or carnitas.

Comment: Why do you need a juicer to juice oranges... last I checked, hands work just fine.

Comment: Probably won't make too much difference. FWIW, when I make carnitas, I cut up an orange or two and cook it with the pork for a while.  Then remove before cooking down completely.

Comment: Sounds great moscafj, thanks. Make that an answer please. :)

Comment: Some store bought juices are really good and taste as fresh as fresh squeezed, they may not be the exact same but it may very well be what you need.

Comment: Yes, look in the refrigerated section of your grocery store, unpasteurized fresh juice is nowadays commonly available...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably won't make too much difference for carnitas. FWIW, when I make them, I cut up an orange or two and cook it with the pork for a while. Then remove before cooking down completely